# 404 error on nginx location directive

Tags: redirect, nginx, location

I am trying to convert my apache redirection directives to nginx one, for now I have the following directive:

```
server {
  listen          80;
  index           index.php index.html;
  server_name     myvisit_head;
  root            /var/www/mv/head/myvisit/;
  access_log      /var/log/nginx/myvisit-access.log;
  error_log       /var/log/nginx/myvisit-error.log;

  # Use gzip compression
  # gzip_static       on;  # Uncomment if you compiled Nginx using --with-http_gzip_static_module
  gzip                on;
  gzip_disable        "msie6";
  gzip_vary           on;
  gzip_proxied        any;
  gzip_comp_level     5;
  gzip_buffers        16 8k;
  gzip_http_version   1.0;
  gzip_types          text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/$

  # error pages
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   /var/www;
  }

  # Deny access to hidden files
  location ~* /\.ht {
    deny            all;
    access_log      off;
    log_not_found   off;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~* /myvisitv3 {
    rewrite /(myvisitv3|myvisitV3|myVisitv3|myVisitV3)([-_])(.*).(html|php)$ /myvisitv3.php?libAdresse=$3 break;
  }

  # Pass PHP scripts on to PHP-FPM
  include global/php-fpm.conf;
  location ~* \.php$ {
    try_files       $uri /index.php;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_pass    php5-fpm-sock;
    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   PHP_VALUE          "auto_prepend_file=/var/www/profile/external/header.php \n
                                        auto_append_file=/var/www/profile/external/footer.php";
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

but when I try to access the url I get a 404 not found error.
I have tried both with location, request_uri directive but the result is the same
here's my apache rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(myvisitv3|myvisitV3|myVisitv3|myVisitV3)([-_])(.*).(html|php)$    myvisitv3.php?libAdresse=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(openVisit|openvisit).(html|php)$                                  openvisitv3.php             [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(favicon).(ico|png|bmp|jpg)$                                       web/img/favicon.ico         [L,QSA]
```

Comment: do you mind if we just use a case insensitive matching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These rules use case insensitive matching to spare us the hassle of handling those so many cases.

```
location ~* /myvisitv3[-_](.*)\.(?:html|php) {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /myvisitv3.php?libAdresse=$1;
}

location ~* /openvisit\.(?:html|php)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /openvisitv3.php;
}

location ~* /favicon\.(?:ico|png|bmp|jpg)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /web/img/favicon.ico;
}
```

Comment: stille getting "
2013/05/15 15:23:35 [error] 5105#0: *280 open() "/var/www/mv/head/myvisit/myvisitv3-etab" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.5.8, server: myvisit, request: "HEAD /myvisitv3-etab HTTP/1.1", host: "myvisit"" error :/

Comment: actually i've tried this: rewrite ^/myvisitv3[-_](.*)(?:html|php)$ /myvisitv3.php?libAdresse=$1 last; and it works, but I would like to keep the insensitive matching

Comment: I forgot a leading slash on the first `try_files` maybe that's the reason ?

Comment: the error you mentioned said `/var/www/mv/head/myvisit/myvisitv3-etab` doesn't exist, what's the actual path for this ? and do you have `root` defined in the config ?

Comment: the root is defined as in the config file I wrote in my post (the problem is that redirect fails so 'etab' which should be the first $_GET parameter stay in the url

Comment: The rule doesn't work unless the url ends with either html or php, your error says that you only tried `/myvisitv3-etab` , if this is the format of the url then we need to edit the rule not to look for html and php

Comment: I have tried with or without the extension and neither the first or the last works, I have tweaked a little the redirect code you gave me and it worked:   location ~* /myvisitv3[-_](.*)\.(?:html|php) {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /myvisitv3.php?libAdresse=$1;
  }
So basically it didn't liked the =404 on the end, any idea? ôO

Comment: Did you try the longer version like `try_files $uri $uri/ /myvisitv3.php?libAdresse=$1 =404;` ? maybe the $uri was the reason it worked.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30058/discussion-between-kitensei-and-tmohammad-abushady)

Comment: not working with the =404, so I just added the $uri $uri/ and removed the =404 and it works now, I've accepted your answer because it lead me to the solution ;)